# 2D array as service response

Tags: ros, python, array, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use a service that has a 2D array response

this is my .srv file

```
uint32 a

---
uint32[][] tree
```

catkin_make error:

```
genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec: invalid field: Currently only support 1-dimensional array types: uint32[][]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232964/2d-array-as-service-response/) by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the error says it all: two dimensional arrays are currently not supported.

I see two possibilities:

1. use one of the `MultiArray` message types in [`std_msgs`](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs).
2. create your service similar to what e.g. `sensor_msgs/Image` is [doing](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html), by having a 1D array for the data and an additional parameter for the length of a row, i.e.

   ```
    int32 a
    ---
    uint32 step # Full row length in bytes
    uint32[] data # actual matrix data, size is (step * rows)
   ```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on 2016-04-27**:
thanks . :)

**Comment by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on 2016-04-27**:
if I chose the second possibility ; do you know how to return step and data to my client node ??

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-27**:
Sorry, I don't understand your question.. This is a service, so the client sends the request, and receives the response, which contains `step` and `data` in this case....

**Comment by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on 2016-04-27**:
I mean how to write it in server but I found this way
**resp=stResponse()**
**resp.step = 7**
**resp.data = cell** #cell is an array in my server code
**return resp**

but I have another problem now:
when I tried to print the received array in client it is printed as (1,2,3,4,..) not as the data that was assigned?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-27**:
please post a new question and provide the respective code (make sure to format it properly using the preformatted text button, the one with 101 on it).

**Comment by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on 2016-04-27**:
I did , thanks a lot :)
and this the question if want to help
http://answers.ros.org/question/233049/array-as-response-in-python/

**Comment by [thejose](https://answers.ros.org/users/55665/thejose/) on 2020-10-14**:
I don't understand how the second option works. Could you explain it in a little more detail?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-10-15**:
Instead of a two-dimensional array, create a one-dimensional array by putting all rows "behind" each other. With the `step` field you define how long (either in bytes or you could also use number of elements) each row ist.

Does this answer your question? If not, I suggest you create a new question where you detail what exactly you don't understand...

**Comment by [thejose](https://answers.ros.org/users/55665/thejose/) on 2020-10-15**:
Thank you! That answered my question.